How can I "merge" these i2c sensor scripts, if at all?
I'm working on a little terminal-based, RPI-controlled sensor array project! The thing is, I'm a casual Java dev with no experience using Python, and all of my components run on the latter. The following scripts contain code I have used to ensure each of the five devices in question is functioning. For now, what I'm looking to do is merge them into a single file that, upon execution, generates a simple HUD that aggregates and displays the real-time numeric readouts (or ASCII art in the case of MLX90640) from each board.
BME688
# i2c = board.STEMMA_I2C()  # For using the built-in STEMMA QT connector on a m>
bme680 = adafruit_bme680.Adafruit_BME680_I2C(i2c, debug=False)

# change this to match the location's pressure (hPa) at sea level
bme680.sea_level_pressure = 1013.25

# You will usually have to add an offset to account for the temperature of
# the sensor. This is usually around 5 degrees but varies by use. Use a
# separate temperature sensor to calibrate this one.
temperature_offset = -5

while True:
    print("\nTemperature: %0.1f C" % (bme680.temperature + temperature_offset))
    print("Gas: %d ohm" % bme680.gas)
    print("Humidity: %0.1f %%" % bme680.relative_humidity)
    print("Pressure: %0.3f hPa" % bme680.pressure)
    print("Altitude = %0.2f meters" % bme680.altitude)

    time.sleep(1)

BNO08x
# SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2020 Bryan Siepert, written for Adafruit Industries
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
import time
import board
import busio
from adafruit_bno08x import (
    BNO_REPORT_ACCELEROMETER,
    BNO_REPORT_GYROSCOPE,
    BNO_REPORT_MAGNETOMETER,
    BNO_REPORT_ROTATION_VECTOR,
)
from adafruit_bno08x.i2c import BNO08X_I2C

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA, frequency=400000)
bno = BNO08X_I2C(i2c)

bno.enable_feature(BNO_REPORT_ACCELEROMETER)
bno.enable_feature(BNO_REPORT_GYROSCOPE)
bno.enable_feature(BNO_REPORT_MAGNETOMETER)

while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Acceleration:")
    accel_x, accel_y, accel_z = bno.acceleration  # pylint:disable=no-member
    print("X: %0.6f  Y: %0.6f Z: %0.6f  m/s^2" % (accel_x, accel_y, accel_z))
    print("")

    print("Gyro:")
    gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z = bno.gyro  # pylint:disable=no-member
    print("X: %0.6f  Y: %0.6f Z: %0.6f rads/s" % (gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z))
    print("")

    print("Magnetometer:")
    mag_x, mag_y, mag_z = bno.magnetic  # pylint:disable=no-member
    print("X: %0.6f  Y: %0.6f Z: %0.6f uT" % (mag_x, mag_y, mag_z))
    print("")

    print("Rotation Vector Quaternion:")
    quat_i, quat_j, quat_k, quat_real = bno.quaternion  # pylint:disable=no-mem>
    print(
 "I: %0.6f  J: %0.6f K: %0.6f  Real: %0.6f" % (quat_i, quat_j, quat_k, q>
    )
    print("")

MLX90640
# SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2021 ladyada for Adafruit Industries
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_mlx90640

PRINT_TEMPERATURES = False
PRINT_ASCIIART = True

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA, frequency=800000)

mlx = adafruit_mlx90640.MLX90640(i2c)
print("MLX addr detected on I2C")
print([hex(i) for i in mlx.serial_number])

mlx.refresh_rate = adafruit_mlx90640.RefreshRate.REFRESH_2_HZ

frame = [0] * 768
while True:
    stamp = time.monotonic()
    try:
        mlx.getFrame(frame)
    except ValueError:
        # these happen, no biggie - retry
        continue
    print("Read 2 frames in %0.2f s" % (time.monotonic() - stamp))
    for h in range(24):
        for w in range(32):
            t = frame[h * 32 + w]
            if PRINT_TEMPERATURES:
                print("%0.1f, " % t, end="")
            if PRINT_ASCIIART:
                c = "&"
                # pylint: disable=multiple-statements
                if t < 20:
                    c = " "
                elif t < 23:
                    c = "."
                elif t < 25:
                    c = "-"
                elif t < 27:
                    c = "*"
                elif t < 29:
                    c = "+"
                elif t < 31:
                    c = "x"
                elif t < 33:
                    c = "%"
                elif t < 35:
                    c = "#"
                elif t < 37:
                    c = "X"
                # pylint: enable=multiple-statements
                print(c, end="")
        print()
    print()

MiniGPS
import time
import sys
import board
import busio

import adafruit_gps

i2c = board.I2C()

gps = adafruit_gps.GPS_GtopI2C(i2c, debug=False)  # Use I2C interface

# Initialize the GPS module by changing what data it sends and at what rate.
gps.send_command(b"PMTK314,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0")
# Turn on just minimum info (RMC only, location):
# gps.send_command(b'PMTK314,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0')
# Turn off everything:
# gps.send_command(b'PMTK314,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0')
# Turn on everything (not all of it is parsed!)
# gps.send_command(b'PMTK314,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0')

# Set update rate to once a second (1hz) which is what you typically want.
gps.send_command(b"PMTK220,1000")
# Or decrease to once every two seconds by doubling the millisecond value.
# Be sure to also increase your UART timeout above!
# gps.send_command(b'PMTK220,2000')
# You can also speed up the rate, but don't go too fast or else you can lose
# data during parsing.  This would be twice a second (2hz, 500ms delay):
# gps.send_command(b'PMTK220,500')

# Main loop runs forever printing the location, etc. every second.
last_print = time.monotonic()
while True:
    gps.update()

    current = time.monotonic()
    if current - last_print >= 1.0:
        last_print = current
        if not gps.has_fix:
            # Try again if we don't have a fix yet.
            print("Waiting for fix...")
           continue
        # We have a fix! (gps.has_fix is true)
        # Print out details about the fix like location, date, etc.
        print("=" * 40)  # Print a separator line.
        print(
            "Fix timestamp: {}/{}/{} {:02}:{:02}:{:02}".format(
                gps.timestamp_utc.tm_mon,  # Grab parts of the time from the
                gps.timestamp_utc.tm_mday,  # struct_time object that holds
                gps.timestamp_utc.tm_year,  # the fix time.  Note you might
                gps.timestamp_utc.tm_hour,  # not get all data like year, day,
                gps.timestamp_utc.tm_min,  # month!
                gps.timestamp_utc.tm_sec,
            )
        )
        print("Latitude: {0:.6f} degrees".format(gps.latitude))
        print("Longitude: {0:.6f} degrees".format(gps.longitude))
        print(
            "Precise Latitude: {} degs, {:2.4f} mins".format(
                gps.latitude_degrees, gps.latitude_minutes
            )
        )
        print(
            "Precise Longitude: {} degs, {:2.4f} mins".format(
                gps.longitude_degrees, gps.longitude_minutes
            )
        )
        print("Fix quality: {}".format(gps.fix_quality))
        # Some attributes beyond latitude, longitude and timestamp are optional
        # and might not be present.  Check if they're None before trying to use!
        if gps.satellites is not None:
            print("# satellites: {}".format(gps.satellites))
        if gps.altitude_m is not None:
            print("Altitude: {} meters".format(gps.altitude_m))
        if gps.speed_knots is not None:
            print("Speed: {} knots".format(gps.speed_knots))
        if gps.track_angle_deg is not None:
            print("Track angle: {} degrees".format(gps.track_angle_deg))
        if gps.horizontal_dilution is not None:
            print("Horizontal dilution: {}".format(gps.horizontal_dilution))
        if gps.height_geoid is not None:
            print("Height geoid: {} meters".format(gps.height_geoid))

APDS9960
# SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2021 ladyada for Adafruit Industries
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import time
import board
from adafruit_apds9960.apds9960 import APDS9960

i2c = board.I2C()  # uses board.SCL and board.SDA
# i2c = board.STEMMA_I2C()  # For using the built-in STEMMA QT connector on a m>
apds = APDS9960(i2c)

apds.enable_proximity = True

while True:
    print(apds.proximity)
    time.sleep(0.2)


ChatGPT and I gave it a shot and got somewhere, but ultimately, not very far. Together, we managed to fetch data from the array, display it, and refresh it at an interval. Here's what went wrong, though.

Upon execution, the console produces an error message that remains on screen for several minutes before any valid output begins.
When the console begins printing readouts, they are erroneously formatted as partial fragments (e.g., only one line of ASCII characters instead of a whole "frame" for the IR cam, only longitude for the GPS, etc.).

Code
import subprocess
import time
import sys

# Define functions to run each sensor script and capture its ou>
def run_sensor_script(script_name):
    return subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, script_name], stdo>

# Define HUD display function
def display_hud(sensor_outputs):
    # Parse and display data from each sensor
    for sensor_name, output in sensor_outputs.items():
        print(f"--- {sensor_name} ---")
        print(output.decode().strip())  # Print decoded output >
        print()  # Add newline for clarity

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Define the list of sensor scripts to run
    sensor_scripts = {
        "BME680": "i2c-air-test.py",
        "BNO08X": "i2c-dof-test.py",
        "MLX90640": "i2c-ir-test.py",
        "GPS": "i2c-gps-test.py",
        "APDS9960": "i2c-light-test.py"
    }

    # Start subprocesses for each sensor script
    sensor_processes = {name: run_sensor_script(script) for nam>

    try:
        while True:
            # Read output from each sensor subprocess
            sensor_outputs = {name: proc.stdout.readline() for >

            # Display the HUD with live sensor readouts
            display_hud(sensor_outputs)

            # Wait a short interval before updating HUD (adjust>
            time.sleep(1)

   except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Terminate all subprocesses if the program is interrup>
        for proc in sensor_processes.values():
            proc.terminate()

Error
*/home/raziel/i2c-example/i2c/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/i2c.py:30: RuntimeWarning: I2C frequency is not settable in python, ignoring!
  warnings.warn(
/home/raziel/i2c-example/i2c/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/i2c.py:30: RuntimeWarning: I2C frequency is not settable in python, ignoring!
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raziel/i2c-example/i2c-array-test/i2c-dof-test.py", line 26, in <module>
    accel_x, accel_y, accel_z = bno.acceleration  # pylint:disable=no-member
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/raziel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_bno08x/__init__.py", line 598, in acceleration
    self._process_available_packets()
  File "/home/raziel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_bno08x/__init__.py", line 803, in _process_available_packets
    self._handle_packet(new_packet)
  File "/home/raziel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_bno08x/__init__.py", line 863, in _handle_packet
    raise error
  File "/home/raziel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_bno08x/__init__.py", line 858, in _handle_packet
    _separate_batch(packet, self._packet_slices)
  File "/home/raziel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_bno08x/__init__.py", line 373, in _separate_batch
    required_bytes = _report_length(report_id)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/raziel/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_bno08x/__init__.py", line 362, in _report_length
    return _AVAIL_SENSOR_REPORTS[report_id][2]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 123*

Output
========================================

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Pressure: 995.852 hPa

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
************-*-*-*---*-*--******

--- GPS ---
Fix timestamp: 4/14/2024 03:39:43

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Altitude = 145.87 meters

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
*********-**--***---------***-**

--- GPS ---
Latitude: 32.963751 degrees

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---


--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
**********-*-*-*-------*---*-***

--- GPS ---
Longitude: -96.697693 degrees

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Temperature: 21.0 C

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
*********--**-**------*-*-*-*-**

--- GPS ---
Precise Latitude: 32 degs, 57.8251 mins

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Gas: 69245 ohm

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
**********-**--*---*---*-***--**

--- GPS ---
Precise Longitude: -96 degs, 41.8616 mins

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Humidity: 39.6 %

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
*********---*-***-*----*--***-**

--- GPS ---
Fix quality: 2

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Pressure: 995.853 hPa

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
****************-----*-*--**-***

--- GPS ---
# satellites: 7

--- APDS9960 ---
1

--- BME680 ---
Altitude = 145.86 meters

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
*********-**--**---**-*---**-***

--- GPS ---
Altitude: 204.1 meters

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---


--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
************-****--***-*--**-***

--- GPS ---
Speed: 0.93 knots

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Temperature: 21.1 C

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
*************-**---*****--******

--- GPS ---
Track angle: 65.26 degrees

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Gas: 69811 ohm

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
************-***-*-*************

--- GPS ---
Horizontal dilution: 1.25

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Humidity: 39.5 %

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
*************-***-**************

--- GPS ---
Height geoid: -24.1 meters

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Pressure: 995.855 hPa

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
************-***-***************

--- GPS ---
========================================

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Altitude = 145.84 meters

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---


--- GPS ---
Fix timestamp: 4/14/2024 03:39:45

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---


--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
Read 2 frames in 1.23 s

--- GPS ---
Latitude: 32.963746 degrees

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Temperature: 21.1 C

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
++***************************+**

--- GPS ---
Longitude: -96.697683 degrees

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Gas: 69868 ohm

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
x++*****************************

--- GPS ---
Precise Latitude: 32 degs, 57.8248 mins

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Humidity: 39.5 %

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
#%++****************************

--- GPS ---
Precise Longitude: -96 degs, 41.8610 mins

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Pressure: 995.851 hPa

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
#%x+*************************-**

--- GPS ---
Fix quality: 2

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Altitude = 145.88 meters

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
%%xx+*****-***********-*--******

--- GPS ---
# satellites: 7

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---


--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
xxxx++***************--**-**--**

--- GPS ---
Altitude: 204.1 meters

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Temperature: 21.1 C

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
xx+x+++*****-*****-*-*-*-****--*

--- GPS ---
Speed: 0.33 knots

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Gas: 70271 ohm

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
xx++++***-**--***-**--**-*******

--- GPS ---
Track angle: 65.26 degrees

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Humidity: 39.5 %

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
++++******-*-***--*---*---******

--- GPS ---
Horizontal dilution: 1.25

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Pressure: 995.855 hPa

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
++********--*-***---*-**-*******

--- GPS ---
Height geoid: -24.1 meters

--- APDS9960 ---
0

--- BME680 ---
Altitude = 145.84 meters

--- BNO08X ---


--- MLX90640 ---
**********-*---*-------*--***-**

--- GPS ---


you dont need to merge in python.   just import the files into one main file. importing modules is one of pythons strong points compared to other languages...

It runs Linux? If yes, use drivers in the kernel, don’t reinvent a wheel.

What you are running into is most likely hardware limitations as seen in this discussion.
You have a few scripts all trying to access i2c around the same time, and all instantiating a new i2c bus, you are likely going to get a headache from it.
Since you have 1 second delays in some of your scripts, I am assuming that speed or timing is not critical for this application. The above thread mentions running each script one by one and capturing the script output instead of trying to maintain 4 active subprocesses, each trying to access the i2c hardware.
If all of your i2c devices can run on the same clock speed (e.g. 100000Hz, rpi default), you can try to create a single instance of the i2c bus and share that between your sensors classes. This would mean having a single script instantiate and read all of your sensors.
